# Does any Sefer / posek state clearly that the cooking of a Mechalel Shabbos is not considered bishul akum even lechatchila?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, bishul-akum

I know that there are a number of poskim who say that food cooked by a mechalel Shabbos befarhesia (one who desecrates Shabbos publicly)[who is not a tinok shenishba] is forbidden to eat like food cooked by a non-Jew [Bishul Akum]. Others say that [lechatchila]  it should not be done, but B'dieved, after the fact, the food is permissible.

Does any Sefer / posek  state clearly that the cooking by a Mechalel Shabbos [who is not a tinok shenishba] is permissible  lechatchila?

Answer (score 2):

I just emailed this question to a friend of mine and I received the following response:

בפתחי תשובה (יו״ד רסי׳ קיב וסקי״ג) בשם התפלה למשה, ובפרי מגדים (שם סקי״ב בשפ״ד סק״ב) – פסקו לאיסור. וכן בקצור שולחן ערוך (סימן ע״ב ס״ב) סתם ג״כ לאיסור. וראה כה״ח סקי״ב סקי״א וסקי״ג סק״א שבפת״ש לא ראה מש״כ בערך השולחן לאיסור.

Pische Teshuva YD 112 in the name of Tefila Lemoshe & Pri Megadim ibid Rule that Mechalel shabbos food is forbidden. Also kitzur Shulchan Aruch 72:2 and Erech Hashulchan.

**האור החיים בספרו חפץ ה׳** (חולין ד, ב – ד״ה מאי שנא): וכל מה שגזרו רבנן על בנותיהן יינן ופתן ושמנן של גוים **לית מינה ולא מקצתה במומרי ישראל**.

The Ohr-Hachim in his "Chafetz Hashem" (Chulin 4b) writes "all which  Chachamim have forbidden...of Goyim does not in the least amount apply to Jewish heretics.

והדבר **מפורש כבר בראשונים** – בס׳ הסמ״ק מצוריך מ׳ ריט בהע׳ רלא ״בשם ר״י מקורביל״ (הסמ״ק) **שגם בישולי מומר מותרים** (וראה בבי׳ דבריו באהלך באמתך פ״כ הע׳ יד).**

This was already clearly stated by Rishonim, smk m'tzurich mitzva 219 footnote 231 quoting Ri M'kurval also cookings of heretics is permitted.

ו**בשו״ת אג״מ** יו״ד ח״א רסי׳ מו שבשאר מאכלי גוים **ספק גדול אם אסרו במחלל שבת**. ועיי״ע מש״כ שם בסוף סי׳ מה.

Igros Moshe YD1 ch. 46 it is unclear if foods of mechallel Shabbos are forbidden like that of Goyim.(see also end of ch. 45).

וראה עוד בדרכ״ת סקי״ג סקט״ו. ועוד האריכו בזה בשו״ת מהר״ם שיק או״ח סרפ״א ד״ה אמנם. (והעירו ממש״כ הו״ע באה״ע סי״ד). שו״ת מנח״א ח״א סע״ד. לבושי מרדכי ח״א אה״ע סי״ח. (וראה מש״כ הו״ע בח״ד סרמ״א). ועוד.

וראה בארוכה **בשו״ת יביע אומר ח״ה יו״ד ס״י**. ועיי״ש שהעיר משו״ת הריב״ש סשצ״ד בטעמא שגזרו בסתם יינם, שלפ״ז מוכח **דלא שייך כ״ז בפתם ובישולם**.

See [discussion] at length in Yabia Omer v.5 YD ch.10 according to the reasoning the Rivah gives for the prohibition of "wine of a Goy" [applying also to mechalel Shabbos], this reasoning would not be possible to apply to bread or cooking.

[ועיין עוד כמה וכמה דעות בזה – בס׳ שלחן מלכים (בר שלום) שי״ד פ״ב ואילך].

[See many different opinions brought on this subject in Shulchan Melachim (Bar-Shalom) (314:2 and on).

Comment: @aBochur Not only helpful, but required. Currently this is an English site. Posts are welcome to include Hebrew texts as support, but at least the essence of an answer must be accessible in English. If a speaker of only English can't gain anything from a post, then it is liable to being deleted.

Comment: Who’s the friend?

Comment: I hope my translation suffices.

Comment: Why is the first paragraph there about it being assur?

Comment: @robev because I knew of those opinions before I asked the question, and I was originally looking for the name of the matirim.